# Need SQL with date chain logic

Tags: sql, oracle, exadata

I want to write a SQL (not a procedure but SQL) to produce the output as in table t2 from table t1. This is needed to do some data validation between between table t1 and t2. I want to extract the data from table t1 based on this logic and want to compare it with table t2

I have two tables t1 & t2. T1 has data like this:

```
Item Id   Date           Item code
A         01/01/2017     10
A         02/01/2017     10
A         03/01/2017     10
...
A         15/02/2017     11
A         23/02/2017     11
...
A         25/06/2017     12
```

Data in tables 2 goes in such way that date chaining is maintained:

```
Item ID   Start Date  End date   Item Code
A         20170101    20170214   10
A         20170215    20170624   11
A         20170625    99991231   12
```

Database used is Oracle Exadata.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I want to write a SQL (not a procedure but SQL) to produce the output as in table t2 from table t1.
This is needed to do some data validation between between table t1 and t2. I want to extract the data from table t1 based on this logic and want to compare it with table t2

Comment: Are there any dates missing in the list?

Comment: No date missing. Any specific reason you asked about it

Answer (score 0):

I presume that StartDate and EndDate are minimum and maximum date associated with item_code in your table. In that case - this is one way to get t2 from t1:

```
select
    (
        select min(t1.item_date)
        from t1
        where t1.item_code = sel1.item_code
    ) min_date,
    (
        select max(t1.item_date)
        from t1
        where t1.item_code = sel1.item_code
    ) max_date,
    sel1.item_code
from (
    select distinct item_code
    from t1
) sel1
```

Comment: start  date and end date are basically telling that Item code is related to item for this much time period. so item code 10 was valid from 01/01/2017 to 14/02/2017